# Empty Folder is not showing for creating a flutter project in location

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart, github, directory

if i created an empty folder in a folder. If i wanna create a flutter project, its not updated to show from android studio where the project location is to be set. I cant find it while creating project

I tried to clone a github repository. but cant find it in location.